# how to implement infoGAN's loss function in Keras' functional API

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, gan

I have been trying to make an infoGAN based on [this](https://github.com/planetceres/infoGAN/blob/master/infogan.ipynb), but it is in pure tensorflow and I can't really figure out how I would implement the Q_loss in Keras (preferably the functional API).

here is what I have so far:

```
def G_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  return tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_pred,
                                                                labels=y_true))

def D_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  return tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_pred,
                                                                labels=y_true))

def Q_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  return ???

def get_generator():
  inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(noise_dim+c_dim,))
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.02))(inputs)
  x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.2)(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512)(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.2)(x)
  out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(784, activation=tf.nn.tanh)(x)
  generator = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)
  generator.compile(optimizer=get_optimizer(), loss=G_loss)
  return generator

def get_discriminator():
  inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(784,))
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.02), \
                                  kernel_constraint=clipping(0.01), bias_constraint=clipping(0.01))(inputs)
  x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.2)(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, kernel_constraint=clipping(0.01),
                                 bias_constraint=clipping(0.01))(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.2)(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, kernel_constraint=clipping(0.01),
                                 bias_constraint=clipping(0.01))(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.2)(x)
  critic_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_constraint=clipping(0.01),
                                           bias_constraint=clipping(0.01), name="critic_output")(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, kernel_constraint=clipping(0.01),
                          bias_constraint=clipping(0.01))(critic_output)
  x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.2)(x)
  outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(c_dim, kernel_constraint=clipping(0.01),
                            bias_constraint=clipping(0.01))(x)
  discriminator = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[outputs, critic_output])
  discriminator.compile(optimizer=get_optimizer(), loss=D_loss)
  return discriminator

def get_gan(discriminator, generator):
  discriminator.trainable = False
  gan_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(noise_dim+c_dim, ))
  gan_output = discriminator(generator(gan_input))
  gan = tf.keras.Model(inputs=gan_input, outputs=gan_output)
  gan.compile(optimizer=get_optimizer(), loss=Q_loss)
  return gan

generator = get_generator()
discriminator = get_discriminator()
full_gan = get_gan(discriminator, generator)
```

In an infoGAN, there is a loss function for the discriminator (here, the actual discriminator output is named "critic_output"), and one for the Q net you have connected after it (here, the 2 layers after the critic_output layer).

Which needs the G_loss value, like here (code from the link at the beginning)

```
# Entropy of Q: lambda*L(G,Q)
q_H = tf.reduce_mean(lambd*tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = tf.nn.softmax(Qcx), 
                                                               labels = c_sim))
# infoGAN loss function: Loss = V(D,G) - lambda*L(G,Q)
q_loss = tf.abs((g_loss - q_H))
```

This is what I don't know how to implement in Keras, I have already found how to have multiple output, which I did in the discriminator net. It has the critic output (value needed to compute the G_loss) and the Q net output. But how would I implement this q_loss?

I havent tried it but I know about the wrapper function for keras' loss function needing extra parameter (example):

```
def G_loss(lambd):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
      return lambd * tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_pred,
                                                            labels=y_true))
return loss
```

althought I have read that it is only for constants (hyperparameters). How would I give it the value of the G_loss function?